# Script fails at import Gtk

Tags: gtk, python-3.6

I've spent some time looking into this and I can't seem to find anyone else with this issue which leads me to believe that I may just be stupid...

I have a few python scripts that attempt to use Gtk to create windows and they fail with the error message "Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused". I've tracked this down to Gtk because I get the same error with the following script:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk","3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

Any and all help would be very much appreciated.